# How to add a PK to an existing table in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am facing one problem. I have a table already create in DB2.

```
CREATE TABLE "DDL12"
(
 "D4_1" decimal(10,0),
 "D4_2" decimal(10,0),
);
```

I am trying to create a PK on this table as :-

```
ALTER TABLE "DDL12" ADD CONSTRAINT "Key4" PRIMARY KEY ("D4_1");
```

But while running the command, I am getting the error saying D4_1 is NULLABLE.

Now, how can I create a PK on this table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is due the fact, that your database "could have" rows having NULL value in that non PK column right now.

So first set the column to NOT NULL (+ make sure having a unique value in all rows) and then set the primary key with the command above.

You can change a column to not NULL like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "DDL12"
 MODIFY "D4_1"   decimal(10,0)     NOT NULL;
```